# NoSuchElementException in Appium Test. Not able to get the Locator correctly

Tags: android, automation, appium

I have attached the Jave Code, Error Log, Appium Error Log and Screen Shot in the Link below.

Test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args ) throws MalformedURLException{
    WebDriver driver;
    //Set up desired capabilities and pass the Android app-activity and app-package to Appium
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("VERSION","7.0"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","ZY223ZMPG6");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("noReset","false");

   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.equationswork.kinghoo");
   // This package name of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.equationswork.kinghoo.MainActivity"); // This is Launcher activity of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
   //Create RemoteWebDriver instance and connect to the Appium server
   //It will launch the  App in Android Device using the configurations specified in Desired Capabilities
   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    //locate the Text on the  by using By.id()
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.findElement(MobileBy.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).click();
   driver.findElement(MobileBy.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).click();
   driver.findElement(MobileBy.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).click();
   driver.findElement(MobileBy.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']")).sendKeys("san.kktikam@eab.com");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@index='1']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']")).sendKeys("A3DGURK7");
   driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
  }
```

Error:

```
Oct 26, 2017 3:57:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 366.46 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.equationswork.kinghoo, deviceScreenSize=1080x1920, networkConnectionEnabled=true, noReset=false, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=ZY223ZMPG6, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=ZY223ZMPG6, appActivity=com.equationswork.kinghoo.MainActivity, desired={appPackage=com.equationswork.kinghoo, appActivity=com.equationswork.kinghoo.MainActivity, noReset=false, BROWSER_NAME=Android, VERSION=7.0, platformName=Android, deviceName=ZY223ZMPG6}, BROWSER_NAME=Android, platformVersion=7.0, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, VERSION=7.0, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceModel=Moto G (5) Plus, platformName=Android, deviceManufacturer=motorola}]
Session ID: f981bf89-4b7f-40e6-8efc-bd1a814b4eee
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:509)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
    at com.appium.test.KingHoo.main(KingHoo.java:38)
```

Error from Appium Server:

```
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow
_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.pac
kageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"4"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/f981bf89-4b7f-40e6-8efc-bd1a814b4eee/element 200 599 ms - 87
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/f981bf89-4b7f-40e6-8efc-bd1a814b4eee/element/4/click {"id":"4"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args: ["4","f981bf89-4b7f-40e6-8efc-bd1a814b4eee
"]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","par
ams":{"elementId":"4"}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:c
lick","params":{"elementId":"4"}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: click
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.click() result: true
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/f981bf89-4b7f-40e6-8efc-bd1a814b4eee/element/4/click 200 3128 ms - 7
6
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/f981bf89-4b7f-40e6-8efc-bd1a814b4eee/element {"using":"xpath","value
":"//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//android.view.View[@index
='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']","f981bf89-4b7f-40e6-8efc-bd1a814b4eee"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility
 id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility
 id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 4000 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"st
rategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']","co
ntext":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","pa
rams":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index
='0']","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.E
ditText[@index='0']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"Could not find an
element using supplied strategy. "}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/f981bf89-4b7f-40e6-8efc-bd1a814b4eee/element 500 366437 ms - 164
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Emitting alert message...
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Emitting system alert message
```

Comment: Is it a native app? how are you getting the xpath expression?

Comment: Yes , Its a native app. I am creating the xpath using uiautomatorviewer.

Comment: Why don't you use the appium desktop inspector?

Comment: Because I am using Appium in command line mode.

Comment: Ok, then you should give it a try to find the element you need by using its id instead of an xpath expression.

Comment: the only locator available in the case is xpath.

Comment: Well, I have had the same problem before. It was because I was using Android 7, but my test worked fine when switched to Android 6. Otherwise, [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7806) could work for you.

Comment: I have added the screen shots with uiautomatorviewer in the below link :

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-QBwnCjr6U9dDUtZEYxbUdCSUk

Comment: Can you please suggest a correct locator.

Comment: @Anjani Kumar can you try `driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.EditText\").index(0)");`

Comment: I am getting error while Using this : driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.EditText\").index(0)‌​");

Comment: It says findElementByAndroidUIAutomator is undefinde for WebDriver,
shown quick fix as  "add cast to driver" but it does not resolve the error.

Comment: I modified the code as below :  driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.EditText\").index(0)‌​")).sendKeys()


But I am getting the error as follows:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver of the given context doesn't implement io.appium.java_client.FindsByAndroidUIAutomator nor io.appium.java_client.FindsByFluentSelector. Sorry. It is impossible to find something.
 at io.appium.java_client.MobileBy.formIllegalArgumentException(......

Comment: Can you please tell me if the xpath for username and password fields are correct as follows :  "//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']"
and "//android.view.View[@index='1']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']"
respectively

Comment: using findElement(By.xpath(""//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@in‌​dex='0']"")

gives following error in appium console : [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.E
ditText[@index='0']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
and after some time :following error lines appear : refer next comment

Comment: [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/8604cf6d-180b-4c8c-a20b-8e49b6a9a895/element - - ms - -
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/8604cf6d-180b-4c8c-a20b-8e49b6a9a895/element {"using":"xpath","value
":"//android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//android.view.View[@index
='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']","8604cf6d-180b-4c8c-a20b-8e49b6a9a895"]

Answer (score 1):

I think that you first check whether your Xpath exist or not. For this I have written one function which works very well. Try this function.

```
public static String checkpathispresent(String strXpath)
{
    try 
   {
      String lead;
      Object elem = driver.findElementByXPath(strXpath);
      if(elem.equals(null))  
      {
          lead="";
          System.out.println(strXpath+ "has no value so setting blank.");  

      }
      else 
      {
        lead = driver.findElementByXPath(strXpath).getText();
        System.out.println("lead is "+lead);

      }
      return lead;

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
       System.out.println("Xpath do not exist");
       return "";

    }
```

}

Also for your problem try with this xpath -
"//android.view.View[@index='2']/android.view.View[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']" Your Xpath must be unique so that it is accessible and do not conflict with other element's Xpath. In your case view with index 2 has 0-8 inner view as per your screenshots.